# Compare pojo objects in java for equality based on all minus few fields

Tags: java

I have a pojo class which has  30 member variables . I need to check for equality for two instances of this class based on 27 member variables' value. How can this be achieved by without writing code to compare each of these 27 members individually?

Comment: "Dumb" but serious solution - use an IDE. Most IDEs like IntelliJ and Eclipse will gladly generate that code for you. See http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/code_generation.html

Comment: Or use `reflection`, but I don't think that's a good idea in this case. Ok, you will write less code, but you add complexity. @BenjaminGruenbaum has right.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum The solution is indeed valid and is one thing that " Venkat Subramaniam" would call "IDE vomit" :) :) :)

Comment: If there's one case to make for reflection in `.equals`, then it is when you have 27 fields. I just wouldn't ever do it either way because of the weak typing.

Comment: I don't agree. It's fast coding, but it adds a complexity. A POJO is a simple class, I do not like to see reflection on it (and beginners who can work on the same project do not like it too :) ).

Comment: The OP does not say whether he doesn't want to type in that many comparisons, or has some objection to executing them once they're written.  The first qualifies as laziness; presumably this is what the situation requires, how long will that take even for a slow typist?  And the second is just what the computer has to do for the situation, there isn't anything to object to there.  I'm left feeling like I don't understand what his problem is.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Thanks for the trick solution, I did my work as a piece of cake.

Comment: @rcook I really don't want to type so many lines as I have other classes also where I have to do the same. No one would want to do that I guess. I was thinking if using reflection how can that be done, but BenjaminGruenbaum's solution did my work in a better and easier way.

Answer (score 0):

Well if you don't mind spend little bit more memory and cpu time to compare this, good way to do it might be use one of json converters to convert your pojo model into json string and compare those two result string.

Pos. You might get exact compare on collections in your pojo model as well, which is not handled properly by automatically generated code by IDE

Cons. You will need a json formatter and diff tool to debug, when something goes wrong.